# How to alter the configuration of robbyrussel theme in oh-my-zsh so that the arrow appears after directory?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-zle

I have these settings in .oh-my-zsh/themes/robbyrussel file

```
PROMPT="%(?:%{$fg_bold[green]%}➜ :%{$fg_bold[red]%}➜ )"                         
PROMPT+=' %{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)'
```

Answer (score 1):

[`%c` is the trailing component of the current working directory](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html#Shell-state). So, put it after that.

Note, however, that your prompt uses all kinds of stuff that has been deprecated a long time ago. There are much better ways to use colors nowadays in Zsh prompts. You’d do well to read up on [prompt expansions](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Prompt-Expansion.html).